# fuzzy matching for SQL using fuzzy wuzzy and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

i have the following table in SQL and want to use Fuzzy Wuzzy to compare all the records in the table for any potential duplicates which in this instance line 1 is a duplicate of line 2 (or vice versa). can someone explain how i can add two additional columns to this table (Highest Score and Record Line Num) using Fuzzy Wuzzy and pandas? thanks.

Input:

```
Vendor  Doc Date    Invoice Date       Invoice Ref Num  Invoice Amount
ABC    5/12/2019    5/10/2019          ABCDE56.         56
ABC    5/13/2019    5/10/2019          ABCDE56          56
TIM    4/15/2019    4/10/2019          RTET5SDF         100
```

Desired Output:

```
Vendor  Doc Date    Invoice Date    Invoice Ref Num Invoice Amount  Highest Score   Record Line Num
ABC     5/12/2019   5/10/2019       ABCDE56.        56              96              2
ABC     5/13/2019   5/10/2019       ABCDE56         56              96              1
TIM     4/15/2019   4/10/2019       RTET5SDF        100             0               N/A
```

Comment: How did you get 96 ?

Comment: @YOLO that's from the fuzzy wuzzy api, OP where is your code?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, i was just making up the ratio for the desired output. i know the various functions in fuzz (ex. fuzz.partial_ratio), but im not sure how to apply them to get the data to show up according to the way i wanted it to.

Comment: And, how did you create `Record Line Num` col ?

Comment: i don't know it's possible or not, but both the highest score and record line num are new columns that i'd like to add to my original table using pandas and fuzzy wuzzy. it's simply what i want to create with python along with the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for duplicates, you should filter your data frame first using the vendor name. This is to ensure it doesn't match with invoices of other vendors and reduce the processing time. However, since you didn't mention anything about it, you can skip it.

Decide on a threshold for duplicates based on the length of your invoice references. For example if the average is 5 chars, make the threshould 80%. Then, use fuzzywuzzy to get the best match.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

# Assuming no NaNs in invoices references
inv_list = df['Invoice Ref'].to_list()
for i, inv in enumerate(inv_list)
     result = process.extractOne(inv, inv_list, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
     if result[1] >= your_threshould:
          df.loc[i, 'Highest Score'] = result[1]
          df.loc[i, 'Record Line Num'] = inv_list.index(result[0])
```